# Camel transaction handler forces reconnecting to ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-camel

Trying to set up a route with transaction handling on a camel, this leads to connection to the activeMQ drop and reconnect every few milliseconds is this expected, is there a work around?

Logs showing repeatedly reconnecting to ActiveMQ server:

ActiveMQ FailoverTransport Successfully connected to ssl://serveraddress:61617

ActiveMQ FailoverTransport Successfully connected to ssl://serveraddress:61617

ActiveMQ FailoverTransport Successfully connected to ssl://serveraddress:61617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed connection factory to use CachingConnectionFactory, also tweaked configurations to incorporate caching connection.